# how to set a default value for select option

Tags: javascript, php

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
 function submitForm() {
  var thelang = document.getElementById('lang').options[document.getElementById('lang').selectedIndex].value;
window.location.href = window.location.pathname + '?lang=' + thelang;
}
</script>
```

```html
<?php session_start() ?>

<?php

require("config.php");

if(!isset($_GET['lang'])) {
 $lng = 'en';
}
else {
 $lng = $_GET['lang'];
}
?>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

 </head>
 <body>
  <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="get">
   <label for="lang">Select Language:</label>
    <select id="lang" name="lang" onchange="submitForm()">
     <option value="en"<?php if( $_GET['lang'] != 'ar'){  echo " selected=\"selected\"";} ?> > English</option>
     <option value="ar"<?php if( $_GET['lang'] == 'ar'){  echo " selected=\"selected\"";} ?> >Arabic</option>
          
   </select>
     
</form>
<textarea cols="70" rows="5" readonly style="resize:none"><?php echo $trans['topnews']; ?> </textarea>


</body>

</html>
```

I am new to implementing translation in PHP .I have a text are in which it loads content from database. once the selected value is English , the text area is in English and once it's Arabic, the text area content is in Arabic .
Everything is working great but upon loading the page for the first time before selecting any language i has an error ( Undefined index:lang in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\shownews.php)
when I select a value this error no longer displays

Comment: instead of $_GET['lang'] check with $lng inside <option> if condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
 <option value="en"<?php if( $lng != 'ar'){  echo " selected=\"selected\"";} ?> > English</option>
 <option value="ar"<?php if( $lng == 'ar'){  echo " selected=\"selected\"";} ?> >Arabic</option>
```